# dropout as the final layer or in every layer to avoid underfitting/overfitting

Tags: neural-networks, pytorch, batch-normalization

I am training a Dense neural network where I am having input as a 3x3 matrix, and predicting the eigenvalues of that matrix. Initially, I was having num_samples = 2000, so my model was not able to generalize well. Now, I have increased the num_sample = 20000, but my model is underfitting. I am not getting should I increase the layers/number of neurons or should I add regularization?

```
class DenseNet(nn.Module):
    def _init_(self, alpha):
        super(DenseNet, self)._init_()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(9, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 32)
        self.fc4_eigenvalues = nn.Linear(32, 3)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)
        self.alpha = alpha
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = nn.functional.leaky_relu(self.fc1(x), negative_slope=self.alpha)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = nn.functional.leaky_relu(self.fc2(x), negative_slope=self.alpha)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = nn.functional.leaky_relu(self.fc3(x), negative_slope=self.alpha)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        val = self.fc4_eigenvalues(x)  

        return val
```

Here, I tuned the alpha after checking with the default value on 2000 samples. I am calculating MSE between true and predicted values.

```
#calculating eigenvalue loss
val_loss = mse_loss(e_val, td[1])
```

[image: Training & Validation loss curve]

Comment: If your model is underfitting, either reduce regularization (like decreasing dropout probability) or add more neurons or layers.